# Change weird Wp File structure

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory

I have to work on a wordpress project,ReactPress does not work and I think I've found why:

[image]

It works fine this way except Reactpress, so I need to turn it back to original file structure. How can I do it? Can I just rename content to wp-content and delete wp folder after adding wp-admin/include back at root folder ?
Thanks

Comment: there's no specific reason for reactpress not to work with that if the REST API is at the expected location, you should raise this with reactpress support. It's possible that this folder structure is necessary for your host to work. Have you raised the problem at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/reactpress/? You'll need to provide details of the errors/problems you're having, not just the cause you've identified. Keep in mind that questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here

Comment: @TomJNowell

Unfortunatly I think this the problem, I can't hook this app with a page in the ReactPress of this wp but the exact same app do work in a fresh Wp install. 
When I try to hook app/page together I get an error in the console telling me  "file_put_contents(/pathToMyWp/content/reactpress/apps/myreactapp/public/index.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

I asked my former colleague who did this weird install he just said it's better this way, he did not added this file structure for a reason, but because he did all of his wp this way
But thanks for your time

Comment: a lot of hosts have a similar setup, it's called a subdirectory install and it makes updating WordPress with provisioners/package managers/git submodules significantly easier as the entire folder can be thrown away and replaced with a fresh copy. On a lot of hosts you don't even see those folders and get a git repo equivalent to the `content` or `wp-content` folder, e.g. WP Engines managed hosting or VIP Go enterprise hosting. That error implies there's additional server level setup reactpress expects or configuration, you should ask their support about this